# Customizing UIAlertController in iOS8

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

As in iOS8 `UIAlertView` is deprecated.we should use `UIAlertController`.
I want to customize it like font color, font family of message label of alertcontrller's view, also change background color of ok button.i don't know the right way to do that.

Please Help!!

Any help will be appreciable!!

Comment: s you can customize the uialert u need to loop in the subviews and change as per your requirement … and pls show your your and ask don't ask blankly how ...

Comment: yah Thanks! but is'n there any better soltion than looping?

Comment: or else you subclass the control or just go for custom view

Comment: Try My Code For UIAlertController in ios8

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have been perform task with them. But I think it's useful for someone.

Below code is working perfectly with my requirements. Please do changes according to your requirements.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                         message:nil
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *setCoverPhoto = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"First Button"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

                                    NSLog(@"First Button");

                                }];
[alertController addAction:setCoverPhoto];


UIAlertAction *deleteImageAct = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"Second Button"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                     NSLog(@"Second Button");

                                 }];
[alertController addAction:deleteImageAct];

UIAlertAction *setImageASNotif = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:@"Third Button"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                      NSLog(@"Third Button");

                                  }];
[alertController addAction:setImageASNotif];


alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIView *subView = alertController.view.subviews.firstObject;
UIView *alertContentView = subView.subviews.firstObject;
[alertContentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty darn good tutorial over at Matt Thompson's site:

http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

Also, how to configure the alert on the iOS Developer Library:

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Steve Rosenberg.but can u give me link for Objective-C too.

Comment: http://pivotallabs.com/uialertcontroller-ios-8/  of course the apple site is in Obj C and Swift

Comment: this will not change the background color of OK button

Comment: tintcolor discussed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795065/ios-8-uiactivityviewcontroller-and-uialertcontroller-button-text-color-uses-wind

Comment: @ CarouselMin is there any way to change the background color of ok button?

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question of how to configure the appearance of the alert view.

Comment: Down voted for two reasons: 1. This is essentially a link only answer. There is no good information in the answer without those links. 2. Neither of these links provide information on *customising* the controller as per the question: `I want to customize it like font color, font family`