# iOS 8: UIAlertController Default Style Color

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertcontroller

I'm using the default style of `UIAlertController`and `UIAlertAction` but I'm getting white text on white background as in the screenshot

Here is my code:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"0237826726" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                    [self callPlaceNumber:@"0237826726"];
                                                              }];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];

UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                   }];

[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I searched for the problem and I found that I can add `tintColor` for the `UIAlertController` as follow but it didn't work.

```
alert.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Is this a normal behaviour or is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795065/ios-8-uiactivityviewcontroller-and-uialertcontroller-button-text-color-uses-wind/26222502#26222502

Comment: It works :), thanks. Add your answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the tint colour for the UIAlertController can be done through the appearance API:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: @AndreaZ Hi.. I am successfully able to change the tint of accessory view added in the UIAlertAction but still not able to change the text of UIAlertAction Button title from the white to the desired one. Is there something else to add?