# Change UIAlertView content with buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have created a UIAlertView. The main content is loaded with JSON and I want that when I click `"Completo" button`, the content change to another variable value `completo`. When I hit `Mapa` I need to open a map. And when I click `Atrás` it should close the alert (right now all the buttons close it).

```
var tabla: String = "" // JSON Data
...

@IBAction func Itinerario(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Itinerario de Procesión", message: (tabla), delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Completo", "Mapa", "Atrás")

    alert.show()

}
```

Also I wanted to change buttons color.

I am getting this advice: `/Users/Javi/Desktop/ElPenitente/El Penitente/Domingo R.swift:87:21: 'UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead`

Comment: Use delegate method `alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex` to do different things upon button click. It is deprecated, which means try to use `UIAlertController`, otherwise some day in the future your code won't work anymore.

Comment: That's one of a good advice, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what the error means is that you should use a [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) instead.

Usage is quite straightforward:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in
    // Do something here when action was pressed
}

alert.addAction(action1)
alert.addAction(action2)

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Where `action1` has a system style `.Cancel` and no handler, and `action2` has a default style and a handler.

Changing the color of the actions can be done using the `tintColor` attribute of the views, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856892/how-to-change-uialertcontroller-button-text-colour-in-ios9).

Comment: Thanks! Which will be the action that let me change the message from `"\(tabla)"` to `"\(completo)"`?

Comment: Just create one `UIAlertAction` for each, and handle what each action should do on the line underneath `(action) in`. And always remember to add the actions to your `UIAlertController`

Comment: I am sorry but I am very new with Swift. When I create an action, a new alert opens and the previous buttons disappear. How can I program just to change the message?

Comment: So you want to change the message on the alert when pressing an action, and never dismiss it?

Comment: One of the action will dismiss it and the other will change the message

Comment: In that case it might be best for you to create a completely custom view that imitates the `UIAlertController`, I don't think there's a way to not dismiss the alert on an action.