# Change UIAlertController text color

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have created an `UIAlertController` like this and I wanted to change the back button (action1) text color. How can I do it?

When I updated the code it worked but when the button is pressed the text became blue.

```
@IBAction func Horario(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Horario de Apertura", message: "\(horario)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Atrás", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    alert.addAction(action1)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil); 

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UIAlertController button text colour in iOS9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856892/how-to-change-uialertcontroller-button-text-colour-in-ios9)

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice @UditS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do that using this

```
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor() // your custom color
```

Comment: I added another question in the main one