# How to change UIAlertController button color universally in ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856892/how-to-change-uialertcontroller-button-text-colour-in-ios9)

But, instead of changing the color in every `UIAlertController`, I want to change it universal like 'AppDelegate'. So, If I change the color in one place, then all the alert controller action button should change to the new color. My question is:

1. Is it possible to do it from AppDelegate? If not, how can I do it?
2. Will Apple approve to change the button color to custom in all iOS Versions?

Comment: [did you missed this in your link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33048905/1066828)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, It's possible. Add the following line in AppDelegate and all the UIAlertControllers will set the tint color!

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can do it. Do one thing:

1. make a subclass of `UIAlertController` Class say `MyAlertController`
2. in .m file in `viewDidLoad` method write

`self.view.tintColor = [UIColor requiredColor];`

it will change the button color. It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is .h file

```
@interface MyAlertController : UIAlertController

@end
```

Below is .m file

```
@interface MyAlertController ()

@end

@implementation MyAlertController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
```