# Different background colour on Cancel action of UIAlertController with actionSheet style

Tags: swift, alert, uialertcontroller, actionsheet

I have a UIAlertController with preferred style actionSheet and a cancel action with cancel style. The issue I have is that as you can see from the image below, the background colour of the cancel action is slightly different from the other actions.

[image]

This is the piece of code I have:

```
   func showAlertWithThreeButtons(alertTitle: String, message: String, defaultTitle1: String, defaultTitle2: String, cancelTitle: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: defaultTitle1, style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        self.baseDelegate?.defaultButtonPressed()
    })
    
    let default2Action = UIAlertAction(title: defaultTitle2, style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        self.baseDelegate?.default2ButtonPressed()
    })
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
        self.baseDelegate?.cancelButtonPressed()
    })
    
    alert.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: alert.title!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.init(name: "SF Compact Display", size: 18) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .regular), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "Grey#444444") ?? UIColor(red: 68, green: 68, blue: 68, alpha: 1)]), forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alert.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: alert.message!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.init(name: "SF Compact Display", size: 13) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .regular), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "Grey#444444") ?? UIColor(red: 68, green: 68, blue: 68, alpha: 1)]), forKey: "attributedMessage")
    
    defaultAction.setValue(UIColor(named: "Blue#007AFF"), forKey: "titleTextColor")
    default2Action.setValue(UIColor(named: "Grey#444444"), forKey: "titleTextColor")
    cancelAction.setValue(UIColor(named: "Grey#444444"), forKey: "titleTextColor")
    
    alert.addAction(defaultAction)
    alert.addAction(default2Action)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)        
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have run the app on simulator and a device and the result is the same. Do you know how I can have the same background colour on all of my actions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change UIAlertController button text colour in iOS9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856892/how-to-change-uialertcontroller-button-text-colour-in-ios9)

Comment: @stackich thanks for you comment but I want to change the background colour of the cancel action, not the text colour.

Comment: try using the same approach with different key in `forKey` parameter.

Comment: @stackich okay, do you know what is the key to change the background colour?

Comment: I don't know, you can try to find it, I am just giving suggestions. If there is no one, I believe that you cannot change the background color. However, you should not change Apple's standard, I have been using iPhone for years and I have never seen a different color of the text and especially of the background on buttons in Alert/ActionSheet.

Comment: @stackich I only want to have the same "grey" background colour for all my actions and for now for some reason the cancel action has white background colour...

Comment: It seems like iOS always does this for action sheets. However, it is not the cancel style action that always has the white background, it is the *preferred* action. The cancel style action will be the preferred action unless one of the other actions is marked as  the preferred action using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620102-preferredaction

Comment: @GeoffHackworth thanks for your solution. I tried it but nothing seems to changed. Again, the cancel style action has white background even after I set the default action as the preferred action of the alert.

Comment: I didn’t say it would change, I just pointed out that it is the preferred action rather than the cancel action that is highlighted (although they are often the same). It is shown in a separate block with bold text and a lighter background. This is just the way iOS is designed to work: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/action-sheets

Comment: @GeoffHackworth you have a point and thank you for the explanation. But until now, I can't find a solution. If you have any idea to help me, please share it.