# How to change background color of items, that shows when I tapped more button in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

[Take look at first item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgdr5.png)

I need to change background color of cell in table view that shows, after user tapped more button in UIActivityViewController 
My code for calling it:

```
NSString* title = @"Test";
NSString *link = @"www.testLink.com";
NSArray* dataToShare = @[title, link];

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 UIActivityViewController and UIAlertController button text color uses window's tintColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795065/ios-8-uiactivityviewcontroller-and-uialertcontroller-button-text-color-uses-wind)

Comment: I asking about table view that shows after user tap on more button, not about view with activities button @Manoj